# How to make item.split method with two arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

i have an array and i go throw this array with forEach method, every array item  looks like "text;text" or "text:text".
I split this items, but how to make program understand which char separate.

```js
array.forEach(function(item, i) {
 // this solution don't work
 var logpass = item.split(':') || item.split(';');
  //do something with this var
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with `split()`.

To split on either character without knowing which one will be used in advance but knowing that both characters will not appear in the string other than as the separator:

```
var logpass = item.split(/[:;]/);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass in a regexp

```
var logpass = item.split(/:|;/);
```

This means split on both the ':' or the ';' characters so something like

```
"text:text".split(/:|;/); // ["text", "text"]

"text;text".split(/:|;/); // ["text", "text"]
```

Answer (score -1):

access elements using:

```
logpass[0] or logpass[1]
```

Comment: I already access in this way, but if i don't split i cant do this like that.

Comment: if you are avoiding splitting, try regular expression, or give more code or explanation.

Comment: This answers a question, but not the one the OP asked.